# Overriding Magento 2 file causes fatal error

Tags: magento2, layout, overrides

I've created an override by copying the original file here and then making my changes:

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/templates/order/create/items/grid.phtml

I have created a layout XML to remove blocks (named "items_grid") associated with the original layout folder, and then use my override file instead. (Assuming I've done correctly)

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_create_index.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="items_grid" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Items\Grid" template="Vendor_Module::order/create/items/grid.phtml" name="items_grid_new">
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

However, when I load the page, I received the below error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getItems() on boolean in vendor/magento/module-sales/Block/Adminhtml/Order/Create/Items/Grid.php on line 132

Note: When I checked my code by updating directly in the core file, it worked fine. It just seems to be this override module setup that's causing the issue.

Comment: Maybe you make a mistake when call function in phtml file. Pls post your code in that phtml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I can't tell how I came to this answer as I received help elsewhere, but this layout XML seemed to fix the problem in the end:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="items_grid">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::order/create/items/grid.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Hopefully, we can learn something from the solution